# Spreading a steel front fork

Tags: fork, steel

Has anyone got tips on spreading an old steel front fork to fit a more modern hub? I've got minimal tools. I thought a car jack might be a good way to go..

Comment: Steel forks don't really cost that much -- I'd much rather buy a new/used one with the right width instead of risking small cracks that could lead to a rather painful kiss-the-asphalt experience later on.

Comment: How much do you need to spread it?  A steel fork should be able to be "sprung" a quarter inch or so, without the need to bend it permanently.

Answer (score 3):

This to be done with caution and patience. I recently did it using a long 3/8" carriage bolt that I purchased from the hardware store. I placed a washer on the bolt screwed on two nuts then another washer. Install the bolt in the axle notch of the forks. slowly move the nuts outward gradually spreading the fork. I did it slowly over several hours although I don't know if it is really necessary. You will want to go 3mm-4mm wider than needed as the fork will spring back a little when the bolt is removed. You must also be aware that the old style forks do not have the recessed seat ( known by some as lawyer lips) to retain the skewer if it comes loose.